# How can I get the gtk window of a C running program through a python script?

Tags: python, c, gtk, dia

Is there a way to get the window in which we are with a `python` script in a running program that allows `python` scripts?

The program I'm talking about is `dia`, that is written in `C`, which opens all the `python` scripts stored in the correct folder when ran. For example, if the simple following script is stored in `.dia/python`

```
print "Something"
```

that's what happens when I run `dia`

```
$ dia &
$ Something
```

So it's easy to import a script, but now what I want is to get the window, to be able to manipulate it (for example do changes on menu) or call other gtk functions, for example to add an hotkey into the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the examples in the python dir of you dia installation?
From inspecting [that python plugins directory](https://github.com/GNOME/dia/tree/master/plug-ins/python), `dia.register_action` seems to be what is used to manipulate menus.

Comment: I've already used it, it allows to add an item to the menu but it doesn't permit to set it an hotkey (called accelerator).
`dia.register_actions` calls `gtk_action_group_add_action` instead of `gtk_action_group_add_action_with_accel` and the hotkey is properly what I need.
That's why I'm looking for something general (not specific to dia), cause dia is not thought to do some things I need.